# Create Materialized View hangs using remote table - even with 0 rows

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

We're trying to create a simple materialized view based on a remote table, but it just hangs.

The view creation code looks similar to this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_XYZ
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
  SELECT COLUMN1,
         COLUMN2,
         COLUMN3
    FROM TAB1@DBLINK1
   WHERE COLUMN4 = 1
```

Now, if we execute the SELECT statement separately, we get:

```
#Rows: 237
#Execution Time: 0.8 seconds
```

That's fairly weird already, but even if we change the SELECT statement to return 0 rows, the view still doesn't get created:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_XYZ
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
  SELECT COLUMN1,
         COLUMN2,
         COLUMN3
    FROM TAB1@DBLINK1
   WHERE COLUMN4 = 1
     AND 1=2 --included this, still hangs;
```

It appears that the result set is irrelevant to the problem itself.

**What could be causing this?**

Additional consideration:
We had no issues creating materialized views based on other tables over the same dblink.

Comment: Is the remote table actually a table, or a view? How long have you left it to see if it does eventually complete? You could look at [support doc ID 1313218.1](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=1313218.1) for some things to check, but if you can't see the performance views (according to earlier comment) you might need to get your DBA involved to help you.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's possible to diagnose the issue without the views. I'll try to summon a DBA to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

query V$session (and v$sqlarea) as these views will provide some clues as to what is going on; you can also check for blocking locks (many scripts available on-line).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to those views. But would like to know what kind of locks could influence a materialized view creation?